# const_iterator implementation in a sorted list class cpp

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, sortedlist

I'm trying to make a const_iterator but I have some trouble understanding it. I try to change stuff to make it work but it won't compile. Can somebody please help me understand what am I doing wrong?
My code looks like that -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

#include "dummy.h"
using namespace std;

#ifndef SORT_H
#define SORT_H

template <class T>
class LinkedList {
    struct Node {
        Node(const T &in) : data(in) {}
        T data;
        Node * next;
    };

    Node * head;

public:
    LinkedList() {
        head = nullptr;
    }
    LinkedList(T value) {
        head = new Node(value);
    }

    ~LinkedList() {
        while(head != nullptr) {
            Node * curr = head -> next;
            delete head;
            head = curr;
        }
    }

    class const_iterator
    {
        Node* m_ptr; // pointer to current node in the list
        bool operator != (const const_iterator other) const {
        return m_ptr != other.m_ptr;
    }
    public:
        const_iterator() {
            m_ptr = nullptr;
        }
        const_iterator(Node * node) {
            m_ptr = node;
        }
        const_iterator(const const_iterator &it){
            m_ptr = it.m_ptr;
        }
        const_iterator& operator =(const_iterator it) {
            std::swap(it.m_ptr, m_ptr);
            return *this;
        }
        const_iterator& operator ++ () {
            if (m_ptr == nullptr) {
                throw out_of_range("out of range");
            }
            m_ptr = m_ptr -> next;
            return *this;
        }
        const_iterator operator ++ (T) {
            if (m_ptr == nullptr) {
            throw out_of_range("out of range");
            }
            const_iterator temp(*this);
            m_ptr = m_ptr -> next;
            return temp;
        }
        bool operator == (const const_iterator other) const {
            return m_ptr == other.m_ptr;
        }

        T& operator*() const {
            return *m_ptr;
        }
        operator bool() {
            return m_ptr != nullptr;
  
        };

    bool is_in_list(LinkedList<T>::const_iterator it){
        Node * curr = head;
        while(curr != nullptr) {
            if (curr == it){
                return true;
            } else {
                curr = curr->next;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    LinkedList& operator =(LinkedList list) {
        std::swap(list.head, head);
        return *this;
    }

    Node * nodeCopy(Node * head) {
        if (head == nullptr) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        Node * copied_node = new Node(head -> data);
        copied_node -> data = head -> data;
        copied_node -> next = nodeCopy(head -> next);
        return copied_node;
    }

    LinkedList(const LinkedList &list){
        head = nodeCopy(list.head);
    }


    template<typename B>
    LinkedList filter(LinkedList &list, B pred) {
        LinkedList <T> new_list(list);
        Node * curr = list.head;
        while (curr) {
            if (!(pred(curr -> data))) {
                new_list.remove(curr -> data);
            }
            curr = curr -> next;
        }
        std::cout << "Getting out of filter" << std::endl;
        return new_list;
    }

    template<typename A>
    LinkedList apply(A func) {
        LinkedList <T> new_list;
        Node * curr = head;
        while (curr) {
            new_list.insert(func(curr -> data));
            std::cout << "Putting into new list: " << func(curr -> data) << std::endl;
            curr = curr -> next;
        }
        std::cout << "Getting out of apply" << std::endl;
        return new_list;
    }

    int length() {
//        std::cout << "DEBUG length 1" << std::endl;
        int counter = 0;
        Node * tmp = head;
//        std::cout << "DEBUG length 2" << std::endl;
        while( tmp != nullptr ) {
//            std::cout << "DEBUG length 3" << std::endl;
            counter++;
            tmp = tmp -> next;
        }
        return counter;
    }

    void insert(T value) {
        // Add first node
        if (head == nullptr) {
            std::cout << "Add first node" << std::endl;
            head = new Node(value);
            head->next = nullptr;
            return;
        }

        Node *curr = head;
        // check if should be new head (when new value smaller than current head) -> add new head
        if (value <= head->data) {
            // add new head
            std::cout << "add new head" << std::endl;
            Node * new_head = new Node(value);
            new_head -> next = head;
            head = new_head;
            return;
        }

        while (curr != nullptr) {
            if (curr->next == nullptr && value >= curr->data) {
                // add new tail
                std::cout << "add new tail" << std::endl;
                Node * new_node = new Node(value);
                curr -> next = new_node;
                new_node -> next = nullptr;
                return;
            } else if (value >= curr->data && value <= curr->next->data) {
                // add new node between those two
                std::cout << "add new node between those two" << std::endl;
                Node * new_node = new Node(value);
                Node * temp_ptr = curr -> next;
                curr -> next = new_node;
                new_node -> next = temp_ptr;
                return;
            } else {
                curr = curr->next;
            }
        }
    }

    void remove(const_iterator it) {
        // TODO: Check if delete all accurancies
        if (!is_in_list(it)){
            return;
        }

        // handle the head
        if (head == it) {
            if (head->next != nullptr) {
                // head is not single node
                Node * temp_ptr = head->next;
                delete head;
                head = temp_ptr;
                return;
            } else {
                // head is single node
                delete head;
                head = nullptr;
                return;
            }
        }

        Node * curr = head;
        Node * prev = head;
        while (curr != nullptr){
            if (curr == it){
                // as we are already handled the head case,
                // at this point we know that curr != head.
                prev->next = curr->next;
                delete curr;
                return;
            } else {
                prev=curr;
                curr=curr->next;
            }
        }

    }

    void print() {
        Node * curr = head;
        while (curr != nullptr) {
            cout << curr -> data << endl;
            curr = curr -> next;
        }
    }

    Node * begin() const {
        return head;
    }
    Node * end() const {
        Node * curr = head;
        while (curr->next != nullptr){
           curr = curr->next;
        }
        return curr;
    }
};


#endif
```

and my main looks like that-

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sortedList.h"
#include "dummy.h"

bool func(Dummy num) {
    int number = num.get();
    if (number % 2 != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

string getLen(string str)
{
    return std::to_string(str.length());
}

using std::string;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

        LinkedList<string> lst1 = LinkedList<string>();
        lst1.insert("Charlie");
        lst1.insert("Bob");
        lst1.insert("Alice");
        lst1.insert("Donald");
        lst1.print();
        LinkedList<string> lst2 = lst1;
        lst2 = lst2.apply(getLen);
        lst2.print();
        LinkedList<string>::const_iterator it = lst2.begin();
        cout << *it << endl << endl;
        ++it;
        lst2.remove(it);
        lst2.print();

    return 0;
}
```

The error message I'm getting is-
(Not all of it is here because it is too long)

```
    In file included from C:\Users\User\CLionProjects\ex2.2\main.cpp:2:
C:\Users\User\CLionProjects\ex2.2\sortedList.h: In instantiation of 'class LinkedList<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator':
C:\Users\User\CLionProjects\ex2.2\main.cpp:40:44:   required from here
C:\Users\User\CLionProjects\ex2.2\sortedList.h:79:24: error: postfix 'LinkedList<T>::const_iterator LinkedList<T>::const_iterator::operator++(T) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]' must have 'int' as its argument
         const_iterator operator ++ (T) {
                        ^~~~~~~~
C:\Users\User\CLionProjects\ex2.2\sortedList.h: In instantiation of 'T& LinkedList<T>::const_iterator::operator*() const [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]':
C:\Users\User\CLionProjects\ex2.2\main.cpp:41:18:   required from here
C:\Users\User\CLionProjects\ex2.2\sortedList.h:92:21: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&' from expression of type 'LinkedList<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::Node'
             return *m_ptr;
```

Comment: Look at the code on those lines.  Correct the code.  The compiler is being very helpful in pointing out that the code is in error.

Comment: I looked at it and I can't see what do I need to change in order for it to compile

Answer (score 0):

> what am I doing wrong?
>
> ```
> self_type operator++() { self_type i = *this; ptr_++; return i; }
> ```

This cannot work. `ptr_++` will move the pointer to the next element of the **array**... except there is no array in this case. You aren't writing an iterator for an array, you're writing an iterator for a linked list.

Instead of a pointer to element, you need a pointer to a node. And to move to the next node, you need `ptr = ptr->next`.

---

As for the compilation errors, look at the error message, and where the error is. You haven't shown where `return *head;`, but let's look at the other one:

> ```
> Node * head;
> ...
> LinkedList<T>::const_iterator it
> ...
> if (head == it) {
> ```

You're comparing a pointer to node with an iterator. Why do you think that would work? What do you expect the result to be? The solution to the error is to not do that.